# How to write a apex class for remove production setting while refreshing the sandbox from production

Tags: apex, community, automation, sandbox-refresh, test-automation

can you please suggest me how i automate the manual customization after refreshing the new sandbox from the production to remove some production setting through apex class.

Noe a days in latest refresh there is an option to give the apex class it will automatically to the needful setting in the newly fresh sandbox,

Bit the problem is how i start writing that Apex class,

Or, is there any other method to solve the problem, please help me i am new in salesforce, but i am very eager about salesforce automation. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

**Run Script After Sandbox Creation and Refresh**

To make your sandbox environment business ready, automate data manipulation or business logic tasks.
At sandbox creation, specify a single Apex class to perform the tasks. This class executes every time the sandbox is copied.Lightning interface of sandbox post-copy script specification

Create an Apex class that implements SandboxPostCopy and specify the class here. For example, the following Apex class simply reports the three contexts available in SandboxPostCopy: your organization ID, sandbox ID, and sandbox name:

```
global class HelloWorld implements SandboxPostCopy {

  global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {

      System.debug('Hello Tester Pester ' + context.organizationId()
           + ' ' + context.sandboxId() + context.sandboxName());
  }
}
```

// Test Class

```
@isTest
class testHelloWorld{

    @isTest
    static void testSandboxPostCopyScript() {

        HelloWorld apexclass = new HelloWorld();
        Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript(***apexClassName***, 'orgID', 'sandboxID', 'sandboxName');
        System.assertEquals(1,1,'Test something');
    }
}
```

[References](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_postcopy_script.htm?edition=&impact=)

Comment: Hi devendra, thanks for your quick response one more thing how I will change the hardcoded thing from the apex class like in production mail id is mail@production.com and after refresh I want mail@test.com how I will do this using test automation . please help